# How to find the request type loadUrl method in android?

Tags: android, webview, get

I am developing an android web app which uses web view. And to load a page I am using the loadUrl method in webview. Is there a way by which I can know the request type of the URL being loaded? I understand that the when I use loadUrl, somewhere internally it is making a http connection. So how I know the request type of that connection?

I tried adding the below just before I call loadUrl, but it always returns "GET" as it seems to make its own new connection and therefore its a GET by default.

//Get the request type

```
try {
    URL actualUrl = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection cn = (HttpURLConnection)      actualUrl.openConnection(); 
    methodName = cn.getRequestMethod();
// It always returns a "GET" for the above.
        view.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can Want to take some help than use this file ( detail , you can send parameters with the help of this file ) :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0nmvn1pxxcsh3ah/WebCallableCoreActivity.java

else use this code :

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(this.url_string);

HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httppost);
```